# Auxiliary mechanical anti-ESD measures

Tags: emc, protection, esd, discharge, mechanical-assembly

If a PCBA within a plastic enclosure is prone to malfunctioning due to ESD air discharge in proximity of enclosure seams and openings, but changing the hardware or plastic design is not an option, what could then be steps to minimize the problem?

The typical system refered to here is a battery powered one but with buttons, overlays or seams that are poorly designed in terms of keeping ESD discharge arc from reaching the PCBA. No on-board protective components can be assumed.

One solution I have come across is ESD protection tape (not the packaging type, but rather Kapton) that can be applied to specific PCBA areas to add protection. Are there other mechanical means to achieve the same goal?

Comment: There's not enough info. How does the plastic enclosure interact with the outside world? How is it powered? Are there user interface items like switches/buttons, connectors etc? And also what means of protection are there on the actual PCB?

Comment: ESD tape doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Do not apply to your PCB. It does not shield from ESD. Might a well use Kapton tape if you want to do that but it may not help. ESD tape comes in 2 forms: low static generation and static dissipative. The first does nothing for you and the second will do nothing unless connected to your PCB or chassis ground. But shunting ESD to PCB ground is dicey if your PCB is not designed for it. You need to intercept that ESD with conductive surfaces and shunt it to an external ground. Like copper foil or tape on the inside surface of the enclosure.

Comment: I was refering exactly to Kapton type of tape or similar, not the low static generation, I updated the question to reflect that. @Lundin: I will add some details, but the question is supposed to be general, not case-specific.

Comment: Connector mechanics _are_ case-specific no matter how you put it. The correct solution is almost always to ground down conductive parts that aren't grounded.

Comment: A board re-layout is your best option.

Comment: Assuming floating device on battery. If a board re-layout is on the table, would you typically recommend a bare GND edge to enable arcing to GND or reversely, pull away GND from edge of PCB and have unbroken solder mask.

Comment: Ok, I'll assume a floating device with a battery in a plastic box with no connectors and no switches. Conclusion: there are no ESD problems and nothing that needs fixing.

Comment: I refer to device being electrically floating. ESD discharge will still arc to conductive surface thorugh seams and openings. For example, think of any TV remote with rubber buttons where the button interface itself does not pose a problem, but the plastic seam does.

Comment: Your question is contradictory, as currently written -- how can measures be "mechanical" if "changing the hardware or plastic design is not an option"? Could you be more specific about what hardware changes are and aren't acceptable? Alternately, if you just want to know about how ESD typically interacts with a device, and what can and can't be done about it, that might be the basis for another question.

Comment: Title updated to better reflect the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the need for future servicing / repair, and the system thermals, you could consider either potting or a conformal coating (the conformal coating being less "final").

Have a look [here](https://resources.altium.com/p/pcb-conformal-coating-types-which-best-your-new-board)  and [here](https://www.coating.co.uk/conformal-coating-electronics/) for some guidance on different types of conformal coating. Most of them will provide good insulation, and it is the secondary characteristics (temp, shrinkage, chemical resistance, humidity tolerance, removability) that will dominate selection.

Comment: Are there potting and conformal coatings that are known to have supperior performance in terms of dielectric strength / ability to prevent ESD arc?

Comment: Most of them will provide good insulation, it is the secondary characteristics (temp, shrinkage, chemical resistance, humidity tolerance) that dominate selection.  Have a look here https://resources.altium.com/p/pcb-conformal-coating-types-which-best-your-new-board and https://www.coating.co.uk/conformal-coating-electronics/ for some guidance.